# Django: Cannot resolve keyword on generic relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to filter my generic relationship by user i.e.

```
Entry.objects.filter(content_object__user=request.user)
```

But I get this message:

**Cannot resolve keyword 'content_object' into field. Choices are: content_type, id, object_id, reason, request_made**

```
class Unsubscribe(models.Model):
    """

    Notes:
    See: http://www.screamingatmyscreen.com/2012/6/django-and-generic-relations/
    """
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, help_text="Represents the name of the model")
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(help_text="stores the object id")
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    reason = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    request_made = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                   help_text="Shows when object was created.")
```

**UPDATE:**

I found this quote:

> Remember that I said there is a little difference between ForeignKey
>   and GenericForeignKeys. You cannot use them in your queries.
>   Entry.objects.filter(content_object...) is not possible. You can use
>   everything else but not content_object.

So whats this is saying is there is no way I can get the x field like it was a ForeignKey?

The only solution I can see would be something like this, but cmon!

```
tmpl['mydict'] = []
for item in Entry.objects.all():
    if request.user in item.content_object.user:
    tmpl['mydict'].append(item)
```

then return tmpl context not the original queryset. this way tmpl only has a list of objects by that user.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? `GenericForeignKey` is referencing `content_type` which does not have a `user` type. Also, `GenericForeignKey` just helps you retrieve the object when you have an instance. Not used for filtering

Comment: Here is ticket for this https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2316

Comment: @karthikr  I all the related objects that the GenericForeignKey refers to have a field called user I just want to filter on that user. For example contact__user or customer__user

Comment: can you not do `request.user.entry_set.all()` ?

Comment: I see, you mean from the other way around? I'll try.